# Problem's are returning errors linking to incorrect file locations giving "The editor could not be opened because the file was not found"

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, vs-code, sfdx-error

I recently did a new install of VSCode and SFDX CLI on a new Macbook.
So versions are recent.
I have updated SFDX since this error but it still exists.

sfdx-cli/7.152.0 darwin-x64 node-v16.15.0

- **What I am doing:**

I am deploying an Apex Class by Right Clicking on the file in the editor and choosing "Deploy this source to org", I have also used a terminal command to deploy source.

- **What is happening:**

Typical errors are being returned into the Problem Log.

- **What is the issue:**

**However** clicking on those errors I get taken to a file that does not exist and get this error (see pics) - [image]

**"The editor could not be opened because the file was not found"**
[image]

Take Note of 1. The Breadcrumbs  and 2. in problems the Class file and exyension a followed by a root path "/" then force-app

see the second error is from PMD it is responding properly and the problem is linked to the correct file, note the start of each path "/" vs "".
[image]

**How can I fix this Path issue,** it seems to be a bug but maybe it is a configuration. I cannot find any other complaints about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was solved in a [recent release](https://github.com/forcedotcom/salesforcedx-vscode/blob/develop/packages/salesforcedx-vscode/CHANGELOG.md#salesforcedx-vscode-core-1)

https://github.com/forcedotcom/salesforcedx-vscode/pull/4246
https://github.com/forcedotcom/salesforcedx-vscode/pull/4241

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce SE!  Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.